# Why is it possible to mutate the value of an item in an Immutable.List?

Tags: javascript, immutability, immutable.js

Immutable.List does not seem to prevent you treating it as a mutable array:

```
const Immutable =require( 'immutable');
const l = Immutable.List([1,2,3,4,5]);
l[4] = 9;

console.log(l[4], l.get(4)) // outputs 9, 5
```

[Runkit](https://runkit.com/stevebennett/608a5e50e08b31001bb06206)

This seems surprising, and doesn't appear to be addressed in the documentation.

What am I misunderstanding here? I had imagined that Immutable.JS was somehow protecting you from mutating things, but I take it that it requires you to stick to the defined API to get those benefits?

Comment: I don't use Immutable, but what your doing here is adding a property 4 to the returned object.  Could you try doing `Object.freeze(l)`,.  And yes, I would assume you need to do `l.get()`..  Immutable is unlikely to be returning an array, from what I remember extending the Array type in Javascript has some historical issues.

Comment: Oh...I didn't think of that. You can do x[4]=9 on any object, even things that aren't arrays, hmm. Feel free to make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Immutable handles immutability internally. If you log the list itself at the end of your code, it reads

```
List {
  '4': 9,
  size: 5,
  _origin: 0,
  _capacity: 5,
  _level: 5,
  _root: null,
  _tail: VNode { array: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], ownerID: undefined },
  __ownerID: undefined,
  __hash: undefined,
  __altered: false
}
```

So when you go `l[4] = 9`, you're actually adding a new property to the list *object*, rather than the internal representation of the list.

If you use

```
Object.freeze(l)
```

before the call, then it works properly

Answer (score 1):

You can try viewing the list's properties to see what's going on:

[image: Runkit Prop Viewer]

What your code does is not modifying the item at index 4, it's adding a new property with key "4" to the object.